# unicharset_extractor: command not found

Tags: terminal, ocr, tesseract, osx-elcapitan, micr

I want create new train data using tesseract. So follow step which mentioned in below website.

https://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301

I got below error while i execute Unicharset in OS X terminal.

**Command:**

unicharset_extractor eng.micrtest.exp.box

**Error:**
-bash: unicharset_extractor: command not found

**I have using below software versions**

OS: OSX EI caption 10.11.1

tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.72
  libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.21 : libtiff 4.0.6 : lib 1.2.5

is this possible to execute unchaste_extractor command in OSx?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem is "Unicharset_extractor" not install in your system. So please install tesseract training tools

*INSTALL TRAINING TOOL*

> brew install --with-training-tools tesseract

Please uninstall tesseract if you already installed it.

*UNINSTALL TESSERACT*

```
brew uninstall tesseract
```

*NOTE:* please read logs while install training tools and follow the steps which mentioned in logs.

It’ll take some more time to install the training tool so you’ll never quiet the terminal meantime.

Please install Homebrew before work out above command.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I'd gotten close to getting the training to work, but your answer got me over the finish line. For anyone else on a Mac, I used http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html and this answer to create a custom `traineddata` file.

Comment: I'm attempting to train for multiple formats of a font family (bold, italic, narrow, etc.). So far, I've only been able to figure out how to train one using jTessBoxEditorFX. Any suggestions?

Comment: This command does not work after Feb, 2019. You have to git clone tesseract and compile it all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build Tesseract training executables; they are separate from the regular Tesseract executable.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

Comment: Hi..It's not clone the tesseract to my system. And also i install tesseract to my system and created box file. My requirement is i need to execute unicharset in my OS X EIcaptain 10.11.1